# Airline's agreement to transport passengers to the U.S. under Visa Waiver Program has expired. Do I need a visa?

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, denial-of-entry

I'm planning to travel to the United States under the Visa Waiver Program. However, I noticed that my airline's agreement to transport passengers to the United States under the Visa Waiver Program has expired (i.e. they are listed with yellow highlight on the [list of authorized carriers](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/assets/documents/2019-Mar/Signatory%20VWP%20Carriers%28March%202019%29.pdf)).

Does this mean that if the airline doesn't renew their agreement by the time of my flight, I can't travel to the U.S.? If so, will I be denied boarding on my flight with just my ESTA, or is it unlikely that the airline will notice? If it doesn't notice, will I be denied entry into the U.S.?

Also, if any of the above, will I be able to claim a refund from the airline, since it's their fault that they didn't renew their agreement on time?

(Most highlighted airlines there are very minor carriers unlikely to transport a large number of VWP nationals, but I noticed Air France was listed as expired, so that prompted me to ask. This question is **not specifically referring to Air France**, however; it is referring to any general carrier that is listed as expired on that list. For instance, Air Tahiti Nui operates between Paris and LAX, and all passengers on that flight need to clear immigration in the U.S. even though they are traveling onward internationally; it's listed as expired so French nationals traveling on its full flight to French Polynesia may need to obtain a visa.)

Comment: In the case of Air France, that really seem like a mistake (or some other situation, like it being combined with their corporate sibling KLM). I have never heard of a major airline serving US markets whose VWP signatory status expired (it's more conceivable for charters or corporate flight departments that fly to the US infrequently), and if it happened, it would be significant news immediately impacting thousands of people.

Comment: @ZachLipton Strangely, KLM is not listed as an expired carrier. I believe that it's by Air Operating Certificate, and since Air France and KLM operate using different AOCs, they are listed separately.

Comment: Yeah I'm not quite sure what to make of it, but tens of thousands of people fly to the US on Air France flights every week, many of them use the Visa Waiver Program, and clearly they aren't all getting sent back to France.

Comment: The consequence seems to be “please remind them of the need to re-apply”...

Comment: @jcaron [Which I did](https://twitter.com/sonic_gparyani/status/1104986989655400448).

Answer (score 6):

Air France is listed as expired, but "Compagnie Francaire a/k/a Air France" is listed as up-to-date. Looks like just a paperwork/corporate reorg thing.

Added by mod:
This answer did answer the question before the edit and does not need to be flagged as 'not an answer.'

Comment: Air France's official company name is "Société Air France".

Comment: Also, this makes no attempt at answering the question. The question doesn't specifically refer to Air France, but rather to any general carrier that may be marked as expired on that sheet.

Comment: Yes, because you edited your question after I posted this answer. FWIW, though, yes, of course you'd be denied boarding without a visa, or denied entry by CBP if the airline inexplicably forgot to check your documents. VWP isn't special in this regard; you are responsible for ensuring you have appropriate permission/documentation to enter a country.

Comment: Nope, the question was always asking the same thing; the last paragraph was just a side note explaining why I opted to ask the question. I just made the question more clear to get answerers to answer the main question rather than focus on the side note.

Comment: @gparyani The original question looked very much like your urgent need was to find out whether your Air France flight would cause problems and that the general question was there to encourage teach-a-man-to-fish answers. Please don't edit questions in a way that makes valid answers invalid.

Comment: @DavidRicherby If my question was that, I would have phrased it as "Air France's agreement to transport passengers..." rather than as "Airline's agreement to transport passengers...", and tagged the question as [tag:air-france]. But you're right; I probably shouldn't have included that side note in the first place as it may cause answerers to be mis-directed.

Comment: The answer is not valid even as it pertains to AF because, as already mentioned, AF's corporate name is *Société Air France*.

Comment: @fkraiem It does seem odd; but it's right there on the list. It's a lot more likely that the name refers to a special-purpose entity owned by Air France, than that some random airline impersonated Air France to the US State Department.

Comment: According to Google it looks like various generations of the VWP carrier list are the _only_ places on the web where "Compagnie Francaire" even appears. The plot thickens ...